# Downloading a HTTPS website and all of its contents for offline viewing in Chrome and IE9?

Tags: google-chrome, software-rec, website, internet-explorer-9

Is there a way to download a HTTPS site and all the contents in it for offline viewing?  I need to save an educational site to browse offline.  It's got videos, links etcetera.  I want it to work in Chrome and IE 9.  The simpler the app the better.

Freeware or paidware.

Need something simple like Websuction and I find wget too complicated to use.

Win 7 Pro.

Comment: If its just one site, also try trial version of IDM...its grabber is pretty powerful.

Comment: @tumchaaditya: Link me?

Comment: http://www.internetdownloadmanager.com/download.html
mind that it is trial version..

Comment: @tumchaaditya: have you used it yourself?

Comment: Yes. on HTTP..but should be same for HTTPS....its just protocol...the pages still are html, jsp, php...

Only thing is it will only download openly browsable content(I am not sure whether this will work for sites which require login)

Answer (score 5):

Wget does indeed have [a lot of options](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html), but I find the `-m` option is very suitable to grab the data from a single site.

```
 wget -m https://www.whichever.info/
```

Comment: I fing wget too complicated.

Comment: Are you sure you find calling a program with two parameters too complicated?

Comment: I don't get the whole command line thing.  Will it download videos too?

Comment: The -k option is also great if the site you're downloading uses relative links.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com) to download an entire site to a local folder for offline viewing.

Answer (score 1):

- PC Magazine has a utility called [SiteSnagger](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,22003,00.asp) (figure 1) that provides an easy-to-use GUI program that lets you download a site. It has various options (figure 2) that let you control what and how much to download. I used it numerous times to mirror/leech interesting sites back in the day—ah, those halcyon days when websites were simple `:-)`.

  They started charging for their utilities a few years ago, but they were free for years, so it’s [quite available](https://www.google.com/search?q=sitesnagger).

  **Figure 1**: SiteSnagger main interface

  [image]

  **Figure 2**: SiteSnagger options dialog

  [image]

---

- You can also use [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/). It has even more options to specify exactly what you want to retreive and definitely [works in Windows 7](http://www.httrack.com/html/faq.html#QG3b).

  **Figure 3**: HTTrack main interface

  [image]

  **Figure 4**: HTTrack options dialog

  [image]

Comment: Will it work in Win 7?

Comment: Of course, it’s not a fancy, driver or anything; it’s just a basic Windows program. The “fanciest” thing about it is that it uses sockets to access the Internet, but again, it just uses normal Windows sockets, not fancy, tunneling or anything.